# how can i remove keyerror in my django views?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, keyerror

I am getting error in my views.py file on line 10. it says that keyerror:'nickname'
I think I am calling the wrong key or something! if you want other code I can also attach that with it also
Here is my code below if anyone can help me with it?
here is my problem/views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from problems.models import Problems
from problems import utils

# Create your views here.

def showProblems(request):
    nickname = request.session['nickname']
    problems = Problems.objects()
    return render(request, 'showProblems.html', locals())

def addProblem(request):
    return render(request, 'addProblem.html')
def addProblems(request):
    return render(request, 'addProblems.html')

def addProblemCheck(request):
    try:
        rawProblem = request.POST['problem'].strip('\r\n')
        rawOptions = request.POST['options'].split('\r\n')
        rawAnswer = request.POST['answer'].strip('\r\n')
        rawType = request.POST['type']
    except:
        return render(request, 'info.html', {'info': '提交内容不完整', 'link': '/showProblems/'})

    myID = IDGenerator().getRandomID()
    problem = Problems(myID = myID, problem = rawProblem, options = rawOptions, answer = rawAnswer, type = rawType)
    problem.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/showProblems/')

def addProblemsCheck(request):
    try:
        problems = request.POST['problems']
        rawType = request.POST['type']
    except:
        return render(request, 'info.html', {'info': '提交内容不完整', 'link': '/showProblems/'})

    problems = problems.split('\r\n\r\n')   #warning: this may be different in different browsers
    for problem in problems:
        arr = problem.split('\r\n')
        rawProblem = arr[0]
        rawAnswer = arr[-1]
        rawOptions = arr[1: -1]

        myID = IDGenerator().getRandomID()
        newProblem = Problems(myID = myID, problem = rawProblem, options = rawOptions, answer = rawAnswer, type = rawType)
        newProblem.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/showProblems/')

def editProblem(request):
    try:
        myID = request.GET['myID']
    except:
        return render(request, 'info.html', {'info': '错误的请求方式', 'link': '/showProblems/'})
    problem = Problems.objects(myID = myID).first()
    if not problem:
        return render(request, 'info.html', {'info': '错误的请求ID', 'link': '/showProblems/'})

    problem.options = '\n'.join(problem.options)
    print (problem.options)
    return render(request, 'editProblem.html', {'problem': problem})

def editProblemCheck(request):
    try:
        rawProblem = request.POST['problem']
        rawOptions = request.POST['options']
        rawAnswer = request.POST['answer']
        myID = request.POST['myID']
        rawType = request.POST['type']
    except:
        return render(request, 'info.html', {'info': '提交内容不完整', 'link':'/showProblems/'})

    problem = Problems.objects(myID = myID).first()
    if not problem:
        return render(request, 'info.html', {'info': '错误的请求ID', 'link':'/showProblems/'})

    problem.problem = rawProblem.strip('\r\n')
    problem.options = rawOptions.split('\r\n')
    problem.answer = rawAnswer
    problem.type = rawType
    problem.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/showProblems/')

def deleteProblem(request):
    try:
        myID = request.GET['myID']
    except:
        return render(request, 'info.html', {'info': '错误的请求方式', 'link':'/showProblems/'})

    problem = Problems.objects(myID = myID).first()
    if not problem:
        return render(request, 'info.html', {'info': '错误的请求ID', 'link':'/showProblems/'})

    problem.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/showProblems/')
```

here i my problems/models.py file!

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from mongoengine import *

# Create your models here.

connect('pyExam')

class Problems(Document):
    nickname = StringField()
    problem = StringField()
    options = ListField(StringField(), default=list)
    answer = StringField()
    type = StringField()
```

Comment: Do you have the code showing where you are actually calling this?
```def showProblems(request):
 nickname = request.session['nickname']```

To really know for sure what you should use here to get what you need, you should know what the keys look like within this `request` object, within the `session` attribute.  Whether it's a dictionary, or something else.  

The keyError implies that you are looking for the wrong key there.

Comment: what code are you looking for? showProblems.html file code or any other?

Answer (score 0):

The error which is likely triggered on this line

```
nickname = request.session['nickname']
```

indicates that the session attributes does not have a key named `nickname` when this function is called on, for example in the following instance

```
 return HttpResponseRedirect('/showProblems/')
```

Check that the key is present and see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/) for more from documentation

**I am also baffled as to why that line is even necessary, do update in the comments if there's anything omitted.**

Comment: Where do i check for the key??

Comment: is this of your own project? Do you see any definition of the word 'nickname'?

Comment: this is not my code! i am trying to run some code from github! and i don't see any definition of nickname anywhere

Comment: I suppose it may have been a custom key created by the author of the project and was no longer maintained. You can infact get rid of that line as that has no effect on the function